# Direct domain to IP and port?

Tags: dns, apache-http-server

So, possibly a silly question but I'm running apache on port 8000 and I want to add a DNS A record to point to the IP.

However I need to make it point to port 8000 instead of the default 80.

So is this even possible for a start?

Namecheap won't let me enter it straight in.

Comment: No, using DNS alone you can't specify a port.  As Aboba mentions you could run a reverse proxy on port 80 that would proxy to 8000.

Comment: Port 80 is in use and I need to keep it active and working, how can I do that and still redirect?

Comment: @SamuelNicholson it depends on what it is being used for. Every webserver has different ways of doing proxying. You may need to move what is currently on port 80 to a new port and have the proxy redirect to both 8000 and to whatever port you moved your port 80 service to.

Comment: Port 80 is in use by IIS and is used for OWA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a [SRV record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) however I don't think most browsers will check for a SRV record and will still connect to port 80. You will likely need to have some lightweight server running on port 80 that will redirect the user to port 8000 or act as a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

From your comments in your question, Add a [virtual website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816576) to your IIS instance that just returns a `301 Redirect` to the port 8000 version of the URL for any requests that come in on your special DNS name. All other requests can be processed as normal.

Comment: Port 80 is in use and I need to keep it active and working, how can I do that and still redirect?

Comment: @SamuelNicholson See my update.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a reverse proxy running on port 80 to handle the redirection.